# Using a ListAdapter to fill a LinearLayout inside a ScrollView layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-arrayadapter

I'm facing a very common problem: 
I layed out an activity and now it turns out it should display a few items within this `ScrollView`. The normal way to do that would be to use the existing `ListAdapter`, connect it to a `ListView` and *BOOM* I'd have my list of items.

**BUT** You should not place a nested `ListView` in a `ScrollView` as it screws up the scrolling - even Android Lint complains about it.

So here's my question:

How do I connect a `ListAdapter` to a `LinearLayout` or something similar?

I know this solution won't scale for a lot of items but my lists is very short (< 10 items) so reusage of views is not really needed. Performance wise I can live with placing all views directly into the `LinearLayout`.

One solution I came up with would be to place my existing activity layout in the headerView section of the `ListView`. But this feels like abusing this mechanism so I'm looking for a cleaner solution.

Ideas?

**UPDATE:** In order to inspire the right direction I add a sample layout to show my problem:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:id="@+id/news_detail_layout"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:visibility="visible">


    <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="#FFF"
            >

        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/news_detail_layout_side_padding"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/news_detail_layout_side_padding"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/news_detail_layout_vertical_padding"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/news_detail_layout_vertical_padding"
                >

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/news_detail_date"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="LALALA"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/news_detail_date_height"
                    android:textColor="@color/font_black"
                    />

            <Gallery
                    android:id="@+id/news_detail_image"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:paddingTop="5dip"
                    android:paddingBottom="5dip"
                    />

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/news_detail_headline"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="Some awesome headline"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/news_detail_headline_height"
                    android:textColor="@color/font_black"
                    android:paddingTop="@dimen/news_detail_headline_paddingTop"
                    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/news_detail_headline_paddingBottom"
                    />

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/news_detail_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:text="Here comes a lot of text so the scrollview is really needed."
                    android:textSize="@dimen/news_detail_content_height"
                    android:textColor="@color/font_black"
                    />

            <!---
                HERE I NEED THE LIST OF ITEMS PROVIDED BY THE EXISTING ADAPTER. 
                They should be positioned at the end of the content, so making the scrollview smaller is not an option.
            ---->                        

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

**UPDATE 2** I changed the headline to make it easier to understand (got a downvote, doh!).

Comment: Did you ever find a nice clean solution to this problem? I see Google uses it in their play store for reviews.  Anyone know how they do  it?

Answer (score 97, accepted):

You probably should just manually add your items to `LinearLayout`:

```
LinearLayout layout = ... // Your linear layout.
ListAdapter adapter = ... // Your adapter.

final int adapterCount = adapter.getCount();

for (int i = 0; i < adapterCount; i++) {
  View item = adapter.getView(i, null, null);
  layout.addView(item);
}
```

**EDIT**: I rejected this approach when I needed to display about 200 non-trivial list items, it is very slow - Nexus 4 needed about 2 seconds to display my "list", that was unacceptable. So I turned to Flo's approach with headers. It works much faster because list views are created on demand when user scrolls, not at the time the view is created.

**Resume:** The manual addition of views to layout is easier to code (thus potentially less moving parts and bugs), but suffers from performance problems, so if you have like 50 views or more, I advise to use the header approach.

Example. Basically the activity (or fragment) layout transforms to something like this (no ScrollView needed anymore):

```
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/my_top_layout"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```

Then in `onCreateView()` (I'll use an example with a fragment) you need to add a header view and then set an adapter (I assume the header resource ID is `header_layout`):

```
ListView listView = (ListView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_top_layout, container, false);
View header = inflater.inflate(R.layout.header_layout, null);
// Initialize your header here.
listView.addHeaderView(header, null, false);

BaseAdapter adapter = // ... Initialize your adapter.
listView.setAdapter(adapter);

// Just as a bonus - if you want to do something with your list items:
view.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    // You can just use listView instead of parent casted to ListView.
    if (position >= ((ListView) parent).getHeaderViewsCount()) {
      // Note the usage of getItemAtPosition() instead of adapter's getItem() because
      // the latter does not take into account the header (which has position 0).
      Object obj = parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
      // Do something with your object.
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Yes, that was the second idea I had but i wasn't sure of the `ListAdapter` and the `ListView` does more magic behind the screens which I then don't do manually.

Comment: Of course ListView does some magic, at least dividers between elements, you would have to add them manually, I guess. ListAdapter (if it is implemented correctly) should not do any more magic.

Comment: I went with this solution as it fits my purpose better (bigger layout, small list). If it would be the other way around I'd go with the solution provided by Flo as it allows reusage of elements in the `ListView` for better performance.

Comment: @smok `LinearLayout` has dividers too.

Comment: This is a down vote for me. Memory issues anyone? There is a reason we use adapters...

Comment: @Kevin What memory issues?

Comment: @DandreAllison dividers? Can you please post a link?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html `android:divider` and `android:showDividers`, looks like it was added in 3.0. @smok

Comment: @smok http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15128652/android-add-divider-to-linear-layout has suggestions for adding dividers without 3.0. Stuff can be translated to Java since you're code does things dynamically.

Comment: @Kevin, would you please elaborate on the memory issues and how adapters mitigate the issue?

Comment: @StockB, I can suggest, that Kevin meant the second parameter of GetView() adapter function. It should be used to 'reuse' views instead of creating a new one for each element in the list. With large amount of items in the ListAdapter it becomes a problem.

Comment: @Karatheodory the author said that the list has <10 items, memory won't  be a problem.

Comment: @Smok, yes, I agree. I just tried to figure out what troubles with memory Kevin spoke about.

Comment: Does anyone else have problems with updating the views using the adapter's `notifyDataSetChanged` method? This works fine on a different adapter I have hooked up to a `ListView`, but it doesn't seem to be working with the one I have hooked up to a `LinearLayout`.

Comment: @jokeefe I suspect that `ListView` registers itself as the adapter's observer via `registerDataSetObserver()` method. You should do that in your activity too, and in `DataSetObserver` implementation just clean the `LinearLayout` and add the views again.

Comment: @smok Thanks. I figured that it was an issue with observer registration, so I actually just went back to using a `ListView` and made use of the header and footer views. It does everything I need now!

Comment: this is one of the reason I hate android for. I don't see why you have to implement complicated solutions, or suffer from performance problems.

Answer (score 6):

I would stick with the header view solution. There's nothing wrong with it. At the moment I implementing an activity using the exact same approach.

Obviously the "item part" is more dynamically than static (varying item count vs. fix item count etc.) otherwise you won't think about using an adapter at all. So when you need an adapter then use the ListView.

Implementing a solution which populates a LinearLayout from an adapter is in the end nothing else than building a ListView with a custom layout.

Just my 2 cents.

Comment: One drawback of this approach is that you have to move almost your whole activity layout (see above) into another piece of layout so you can reference it as a ListHeaderView and create another layout one just including the `ListView`. Not sure I like this patch work.

Comment: Yes I know what you mean, before I started to use this approach I also didn't like the idea of having my activity layout separated into multiple files. But when I saw that the overall layout looked as I expected to look I didn't mind about the separation as it's only separated into two files. One thing you must be aware of, the ListView must not have an empty view as this will hide your list header when there are no list items.

Comment: Also, if you want to have multiple lists on a page this doesn't really work. Does anyone have an example of a custom adapter view that outputs items into a "flat" list, i.e one that does not scroll.

Answer (score 0):

Set your view to main.xml onCreate, then inflate from row.xml

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="450dp" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/mainListView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/size"
            android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
            android:gravity="fill_vertical|fill_horizontal"
            android:horizontalSpacing="15dp"
            android:isScrollContainer="true"
            android:numColumns="1"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:smoothScrollbar="true"
            android:stretchMode="columnWidth" >

</ListView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/size"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="#ff444444"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="#D3D3D3"
        android:textStyle="italic" />

    </EditText>

</RelativeLayout>
```

row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
  android:paddingTop="3dp">

<TextView
  android:id="@+id/rowTextView"
  android:layout_width="0dip"
  android:layout_height="41dp"
  android:layout_margin="4dp"
  android:layout_weight="2.83"
  android:ellipsize="end"
  android:gravity="center_vertical"
  android:lines="1"
  android:text="John Doe"
  android:textColor="@color/color_white"
  android:textSize="23dp" >
</TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I think you miss understood the question. He don't want to populate a list with LinearLayouts.

Comment: "How do I connect a ListAdapter to a LinearLayout or something similar?" Just answering what the OP asked

Comment: No he don't want to use a ListView. He only want to use an adapter and use it to populate a LinearLayout with entries.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but @Flo is correct. I **can't** use a ListView because the outer layout is already a ScrollView. Please check my text and the sample layout.

Comment: why is that scrollView needed?

Comment: @fasheikh It's needed because by "list content" just a part of the info I want to display on that screen. Gallery, TextView etc comes before the list content.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. Basically, you want a textView above the list?

Comment: @fasheikh I have a full layout and with a lot of content (so I need the `ScrollView`) and now I just want to add *some* data via a `ListAdapter`.

Comment: sorry @StefanHoth I'm all outta ideas :| I did think to make the primary layout a relative one, and set it to Scrollable but i'm not sure that'll work.

Answer (score 0):

I use following code which replicate adapter functionality with `ViewGroup` and `TabLayout`. Good thing about this is that if you change your list and bind again, it will only affect changed items:

Usage:

```
val list = mutableListOf<Person>()
layout.bindChildren(list, { it.personId }, { bindView(it) }, {d, t ->bindView(d, t)})
list.removeAt(0)
list+=newPerson
layout.bindChildren(list, { it.personId }, { bindView(it) }, {d, t ->bindView(d, t)})
```

For `ViewGroups`:

```
fun <Item, Key> ViewGroup.bindChildren(items: List<Item>, id: (Item) -> Key, view: (Item) -> View, bind: (Item, View) -> Unit) {
    val old = children.map { it.tag as Key }.toList().filter { it != null }
    val new = items.map(id)

    val add = new - old
    val remove = old - new
    val keep = new.intersect(old)

    val tagToChildren = children.associateBy { it.tag as Key }
    val idToItem = items.associateBy(id)

    remove.forEach { tagToChildren[it].let { removeView(it) } }
    keep.forEach { bind(idToItem[it]!!, tagToChildren[it]!!) }
    add.forEach { id -> view(idToItem[id]!!).also { it.tag = id }.also { addView(it, items.indexOf(idToItem[id])) } }
}
```

For `TabLayout` I have this:

```
fun <Item, Key> TabLayout.bindTabs(items: List<Item>, toKey: (Item) -> Key, tab: (Item) -> TabLayout.Tab, bind: (Item, TabLayout.Tab) -> Unit) {
    val old = (0 until tabCount).map { getTabAt(it)?.tag as Key }
    val new = items.map(toKey)

    val add = new - old
    val remove = old - new
    val keep = new.intersect(old)

    val tagToChildren = (0 until tabCount).map { getTabAt(it) }.associateBy { it?.tag as Key }
    val idToItem = items.associateBy(toKey)

    remove.forEach { tagToChildren[it].let { removeTab(it) } }
    keep.forEach { bind(idToItem[it]!!, tagToChildren[it]!!) }
    add.forEach { key -> tab(idToItem[key]!!).also { it.tag = key }.also { addTab(it, items.indexOf(idToItem[key])) } }
}
```