# how to add seprater in between edittext and button

Tags: android

how do i add line seprater in betwen  edittext and button below is my code help me plz i follow this tutorial [How to add (vertical) divider to a horizontal LinearLayout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15128652/android-add-divider-to-linear-layout) is not help me pl i just want to add line seprate rin bedtween edittext and button

```
 <RelativeLayout  

 android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
 android:background="#a8a8a8"
android:layout_width="fill_parent">  
<EditText  
    android:id="@+id/EditText01"  
    android:hint="Enter some text..."  
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
     android:background="#a8a8a8"
     android:paddingTop="15dp"
     android:hint="SEARCH SCHOOL BY NAME"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/Button01"  
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

</EditText> 



<Button  
    android:id="@+id/Button01"  
    android:text="Press Here!"  
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"  
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>  
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put `<View/>` between Edit text and Button as below..

```
<View
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
    android:background="@color/Gray" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using a relative layout so you can adjust the spacing however you want to in the layout view.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `LinearLayout` instead of the `RelativeLayout`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#000000"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#a8a8a8" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/test_button_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/icon" >
    </ImageView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/test_button_text2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/test_button_image"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/test_button_image"
        android:text="San Diego Unified"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="20sp" >
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/test_button_text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/test_button_text2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/test_button_text2"
        android:text="SCHOOL DISTRICT"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" >
    </TextView>
</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="HEALTHY BODIES HEALTHY MINDS "
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/facebook" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/twitter"
        android:text="Button Text" />
</LinearLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#a8a8a8" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/EditText01"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/seperator"
        android:background="#a8a8a8"
        android:hint="SEARCH SCHOOL BY NAME"
        android:paddingTop="15dp" >
    </EditText>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/seperator"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Button01"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/Button01"
        android:background="@android:color/white" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="Press Here!" >
    </Button>
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#a8a8a8" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/test_button_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/icon" >
    </ImageView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/test_button_text2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/test_button_image"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/test_button_image"
        android:m=""
        android:text="San Diego Unified"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="20sp" >
    </TextView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: this is my full code help me how i place divider in between edittext and button

Comment: Check it out, I added the seperator

Comment: @IonAalbers how can you use same property twice ? android:hint="Enter some text..."
        android:hint="SEARCH SCHOOL BY NAME"  for more clarification see my answer !

Answer (score 0):

If you use a Linear Layout, it gives you the option to set a divider and its spacing.

If you need it in Relative Layout, you might consider creating a View and attaching it onto the bottom of the edit text with some margin

Hope this helps

Comment: youre using relative so you can put your view anuywhere with respect to each other

Answer (score 0):

Please check **android:hint="SEARCH SCHOOL BY NAME"** here you will be getting error, because you can't use `**android:hint=""**` this or any other property twice !

Check your below Code :

```
<EditText  
    android:id="@+id/EditText01"  
    android:hint="Enter some text..."  
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
     android:background="#a8a8a8"
     android:paddingTop="15dp"
     android:hint="SEARCH SCHOOL BY NAME"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/Button01"  
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```

**So change it to :**

either use `android:hint="Enter some text..."`

or

```
android:hint="SEARCH SCHOOL BY NAME"
```

**Edit:**

if you are still not able to draw seprater

**Try** :

```
   <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#a8a8a8" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/EditText01"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/my_view"
        android:background="#a8a8a8"
        android:hint="Enter some text..."
        android:paddingTop="15dp" >
    </EditText>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/my_view"
        android:layout_width="5dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/EditText01"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/Button01"
        android:background="#fff" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="Press Here!" >
    </Button>
</RelativeLayout>
```