# How to align elements horizontally within a LinearLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-layout-weight

[image]

I am not able to control the height of the `LinearLayout`. These won't align properly and won't fill up the width. I want the divider to be in the center and both the buttons on either side. Here is my code:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/buttonFieldsLayout"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/loginFieldsLayout" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/signUpButton"
        style="@style/AuthButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/sign_up_button_label" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/buttonDivider"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/divider" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/cancelButton"
        style="@style/AuthButton"
        android:text="@string/cancel_button_label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**divider.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="oval" >
<gradient 
    android:startColor="@color/white"
    android:centerColor="@color/blue"
    android:endColor="@color/white" />
</shape>
```

**Update 1:**

View still sticks out after @Onik's suggestion

[image]

**Update 2:**

I removed the `View` element and added this code in `LinearLayout` instead and it worked!

```
android:divider="@drawable/divider"
android:showDividers="middle"
```

**Note:** `android:divider` property is available only in `Android` 3.0 (API level 11) or higher.

Actually this link helped me and shows the proper way to put a divider: [How to add (vertical) divider to a horizontal LinearLayout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15128652/how-to-add-vertical-divider-to-a-horizontal-linearlayout)

Comment: If you do that, make the outer LinearLayout `layout_width="fill_parent"` and the inner buttons `layout_width="0dp"`, you should be good.  If that gets you stuck, I'd like to see that code and will be happy to help further.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use `layout_weight` attribute for `Buttons`. To prevent `divider` to fill the height of the layout (like entire height of the screen in the picture) use `layout_height="match_parent"` instead of `layout_height="wrap_content"`. This will fill the screen's (or parent's) width and set the `button's` width to be equal, with the `divider` between them of same height:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/buttonFieldsLayout"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/loginFieldsLayout" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/signUpButton"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="sign_up_button_label" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/buttonDivider"
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/divider" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/cancelButton"
    android:text="cancel_button_label"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Use RelativeLayout instead, with `android:layout_width="match_parent"`.

For the divider, set `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"`

For the buttons, set:

```
android:layout_toRightOf="@id/buttonDivider"
```

...And...

```
android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/buttonDivider"
```