# notifyDataSetChanged() does not call getView() on adapter that draws to a LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-linearlayout, android-adapter

I have a custom adapter derived from `ArrayAdapter` that overrides `getView()` that we'll call `CustomObjectAdapter`. I manually add `View`s created by the adapter to a LinearLayout like below:

```
m_adapter = new CustomObjectAdapter(this.getApplicationContext(), 
                                    R.layout.custom_object_layout, 
                                    m_customObjectArrayList);
m_linearLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.custom_object_list_linear_layout);

for (int i = 0; i < m_adapter.getCount(); i++) {
    // Create the view for the custom object
    View view = m_adapter.getView(i, null, null);
    m_linearLayout.addView(view);
}
```

I populate a `LinearLayout` with `View`s instead of using a `ListView`, because I it's contained within a `Fragment` in which I want the entire area to be scrollable--rather than just the area within the `ListView`. I found this solution in this StackOverflow question: [Using a ListAdapter to fill a LinearLayout inside a ScrollView layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12405575/using-a-listadapter-to-fill-a-linearlayout-inside-a-scrollview-layout).

In the same class that these `View`s get populated, the data used in the adapter's `getView()` method is updated and then I call `m_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`. The `getView()` function is not getting called subsequently, however. In another area of the code I am updating a adapter that's hooked up to a `ListView` in the same manner (instead of a `LinearLayout`), and it is updating appropriately. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: An alternative rather than a solution, but you might consider the `addHeaderView` and `addFooterView` in [`ListView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html) in the future when you want non-list items to also be scrollable.

Comment: @blahdiblah Thank you--I coincidentally began refactoring my code exactly as you describe using the `addHeaderView` method immediately after posting this question, and it works perfectly now! If you add your above comment to your answer, I'll accept it as the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative rather than a solution, but you could use the `addHeaderView` and `addFooterView` methods in [`ListView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html) to make non-list items also be scrollable.

Comment: Thank you! This solution was exactly what I was looking for. I also appreciated the explanation you provided in your other answer!

Answer (score 1):

LinearLayouts aren't built to use adapters.  The reason `getView` isn't being called is because there's no view connected to the adapter to tell it that new views need to be generated.

In your code there's no direct connection between the adapter and the view as there is when you call `setAdapter` on a ListView.  As far as the LinearLayout's concerned, the views in it could be coming from anywhere.  Similarly, the adapter can't really do anything with the news that its dataset changed because it's not connected to anything that asks it to generate views.

Views are regenerated with the ListView because it registers a [DataSetObserver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DataSetObserver.html) with the adapter and then requests new views from the adapter when notified of changes via that observer.

There's no comparable mechanism for a LinearLayout, so your only real option is to empty the views out of it and put them in again manually like you do initially.