# ListView header instead of being in scrollview

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-scrollview

I'm having a fragment that shows the image and the name of my items and below that I want to show a list of comments on that item. However it seems I cannot use a listview inside my Scrollview. People are suggesting to use header for my listview. But I'm very confused since my header is not static and is different for every item ( I have to get and populate the imageview and textview by an http call). Can someone help me with this issue by providing a simple example or link?

I read this [Using a ListAdapter to fill a LinearLayout inside a ScrollView layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12405575/using-a-listadapter-to-fill-a-linearlayout-inside-a-scrollview-layout) but I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: Perhaps you could add a layout xml from your app showing the listview inside the scrollview. Even though that would obviously never actually work, it would give us a better picture of what you're trying to achieve.  I'd like to know what is in your layout that requires a scrollview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it this way:
I created an xml layout for my listview (list_layout.xml) with id "list"
and another xml layout for my header (header_layout.xml). Then in my fragment
in onCreateView did this:

```
 View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_layout, container, false);

    ListView listView= (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.list);
    View header = inflater.inflate(R.layout.header_layout,listView, false);
    listView.addHeaderView(header, null, false);
    adapter = new Adapter...
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    //lets say you have a text view in your header. This is how you set it
    //pay attention how used **header** NOT v as the view
    Name_textview=(TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.photo_number);
```

Answer (score 0):

use ViewPager  as a headerView of listView.

and then manupulate the ViewPager state yourself :(load update show)..

Comment: I fixed it without viewpager

Answer (score 0):

If you want a header that scrolls with the list of comments, look at the [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html).  You can find many examples and tutorials online.  It allows you to create a list of items, but how an item is displayed can change.  The [RecyclerView.Adapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html)  determines how to display things, so that is where you will want to focus.

They are a number of tutorials out there, so I won't bother copy/pasting code in here.