# make the activity scrollable with two listView

Tags: android

I have two `lisView` in `RelativeLayout` , when the first list is exceed the second list goes down the screen and when i change the screen to landscap mode the second list again goes down. So I want to make the screen scrollable.

> Here's my xml code,

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
tools:context="com.neemshade.moneyflow.phase1.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/purchase"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="PURCHASE"/>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/outstandingPurchaseList"
        android:paddingTop="3dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/purchase"
        android:scrollbars="none">

    </ListView>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sale"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:paddingTop="50dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="SALE"
        android:layout_below="@+id/outstandingPurchaseList"/>


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/outstandingSaleList"
        android:paddingTop="3dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/sale"
        android:scrollbars="none">

    </ListView>
```

Comment: Batter to use Section list , if you don't want to scroll both separately

Comment: https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-merge One ListView, two adapters in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Two ListView and scrolling your page at a time is bad practice and can cause performance issue. Try to use NestedScrollView insted of just ListView and ScrollView.

Refer this link : 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/NestedScrollView.html

Comment: `NestedScrollView` really solved my problem, it worked both portraid and landscape mode. Thank you **Prag's**

Comment: @Narendhran Glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

The one you are using is not the best practice ever. Having multiple scrolling items with the same scroll direction is usually complicated.

The first and probably easier solution for you would probably be using a single `ListView` instead of two.

To achieve this, you can create a `generic object` containing values of both your items.

Example:

```
class myItem1{
  private String name;
  private int age;
  //...
}

class MyItem2{
  private String surname;
  private boolean male;
  //...
}
```

Now create a new `class` containing both object's variables.

```
class MyGenericItem{
  private boolean isItem1;
  private String name;
  private int age;
  private String surname;
  private boolean male;

  //could be useful creating the two constructors accepting the items
  public MyGenericItem(MyItem1 item){
    this.name = item.name;
    this.age = item.age;
    this.isItem1 = true;
  }
  public MyGenericItem(MyItem2 item){
    this.surname = item.surname;
    this.male = item.male;
    this.isItem1 = false;
  }
  //...
```

Now when you create the `list of items` to be put inside your `list`, do like this.

```
ArrayList<MyGenericItem> items = new ArrayList();
//now add all Items1 as MyGenericItem (cast them) to the list
//now add all Items2 as MyGenericItem (cast them) to the list
```

Now create an `adapter` accepting this new `Generic Item` and manage inside the `adapter` itself if the item is `Item1` or if it's `Item2` (use the boolean).

You will need to create a `layout` with both possibilities and change visibilities and `fields's names` depending on if the item is an `Item1` or an `Item2`.

---

Another possibility is using a `LinearLayout` instead of a `ListView`.

In this way you simply use two `LinearLayout` and they will be placed one below the other. [You can refer from this SO question on how to use a LinearLayout as a listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12405575/using-a-listadapter-to-fill-a-linearlayout-inside-a-scrollview-layout). The result will be the same, they scroll but since they are `LinearLayouts` they will scroll until the end of the first before showing the second.

Hope this helps, good luck.

Comment: Iam new to android, your reff is very usefull to me. Thanks for your kind reference.

Comment: @Narendhran glad it helped solving your problem :)

Comment: I have one doubt, whether iam using as you said, how can i specify some spaces between one list to another and a header for the specific list? is this possible while using your solution??

Comment: @Narendhran If you are using the single listView solution, you have to add a custom header as a line. You have to add another item where you want the new header and you have to manage it manually to customize it. If you are using the LinearLayut solution, simply add anything you need between the two layouts